# Show that any closed ball in $E$ is entirely contained in at least one set $U_i$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

[image]

---

Assume that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a closed ball in $E$ of radius $\epsilon$ that is not contained in any of the sets $U_i$. As suggested, consider the sequence of closed balls $\bar B(p_1,1), \bar B(p_2,\frac{1}{2}), \bar B(p_3,\frac{1}{3})$ none of which is contained entirely in any of the sets $U_i$. The set $A=\{p_1,p_2,\ldots\}$ is a closed subset of a compact metric space, so it is itself compact, thus it must contain a limit point which we denote by $p$. We know that $p\in E$, so there must be some $U_j$ such that $p\in U_j$. Since $U_j$ is open, there is some open ball $B(p,r)$ entirely contained in $U_j$. Now since $p$ is a limit point of $A$, each neighbourhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points from $A$, i.e. a ball $B(p,r/2)$ contains infinitely many points from $A$, so we can choose one of such points $p_n\in B(p,r/2)$ with $n$ big enough such that $B(p_n,\frac{1}{n})\subset B(p,r) \subset U_j$, contradiction.

I have doubts if my reasoning is correct, since I did not used fact that balls were closed. Could anyone verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is not necessarily closed, but that does not matter: any sequence has a cluster point in the compact metric space $E$ (which is all we need).

Using your $r$ we indeed get infinitely many $p_i$ that are in $B(p, \frac{r}{2})$ so for some large enough index $n$ we indeed have that $B(p, \frac{1}{n}) \subseteq B(p, \frac{r}{2})$. *But* we need (for a contradiction) to see that $\overline{B(p_n, \frac{1}{n})}$ (with centre $p_n$, not $p$!) is a subset of $U_j$. For this it suffices that $B(p_n, \frac{1}{n}) \subseteq B(p, \frac{r}{2})$ because then the closure is a subset of the $\{x: d(p,x) \le \frac{r}{2}\}$ (the closed ball), which is a subset of $B(p, r) \subseteq U_j$, which would give the contradiction.

So you need to argue that there exists $n$ such that $B(p_n, \frac{1}{n}) \subset B(p, \frac{r}{2})$. Can you do that?

Extra hint: Choose $p_n$ so large that both $d(p_n, p) < \frac{r}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{r}{4}$. The triangle inequality shows that $B(p_n, \frac{1}{n}) \subseteq B(p, \frac{r}{2})$

Comment: If $p$ is a limit point of $A$ then $B(p_n, \frac{1}{n}) \subset B(p, \frac{r}{2})$ contains infinitely many points from $A$, so we can always find $n$ such that $B(p_n, \frac{1}{n}) \subset B(p, \frac{r}{2})$? Does this argument make sense? Also, I still dont't see how the fact that balls are closed is used here.

Comment: Your first argument makes no sense yet. The closedness is not really used, but we need the **closure** of the ball (by how the theorem is formulated and how the $p_n$ are chosen) to be inside $B(p,r)$, hence the $\frac{r}{2}$ to give us some room, as I said at the end.

Comment: Could you provide the final argument? Somehow I can't figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: @luka5z see the extra hint.